# How to use enum to save jsx in react/typescript

Tags: typescript, jsx

```
enum result{
    fail=（<StyleDiv>fail</StyleDiv>）,
 success=（<StyleDiv>success</StyleDiv>）
}
function(){
return result.fail
}
```

How can i do this?
Should i change ways to do this?

Comment: Why do you need an enum here? You could use a regular object

Comment: I agree with @Aleksey L. Just create an object and add 'as const' . Please avoid numerical enums, they are unsafe. Also enums are mutable, so you better to get rid them from your codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object with keys as enum members:

```
enum resultKeys {
  fail,
  success,
}

const result = {
  [resultKeys.fail]: <StyleDiv>fail</StyleDiv>,
  [resultKeys.success]: <StyleDiv>success</StyleDiv>, 
};
```

Or if every member of `result` is the same `StyleDiv` component you can store only children as the value of each key in result:

```
enum resultKeys {
  fail,
  success,
}

const result = {
  [resultKeys.fail]: "fail",
  [resultKeys.success]: "success", 
};

function getStyleDiv(key: resultKeys): JSX.Element {
  return <StyleDiv>{result[key]}</StyleDiv>;
}

const fail = getStyleDiv(resultKeys.fail);
```